# argparse positional argument with nargs set to '?'

Tags: python, argparse

I want to make a list command that lists all items with:

```
python file.py list
```

I also want it to accept a filter query e.g. to list all items with the string "cat" in it would be:

```
python file.py list cat
```

I have done the following to achieve this, which seems to work:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("action", choices=["list"])
parser.add_argument("query",type=str,nargs='?')
```

I am curious to know why it is allowed to create a positional argument query, with the possibility of not suppling anything for it by using nargs='?'? I mean, positional arguments have required=True by default and setting required=False is not allowed.

Comment: '?' means 0 or 1 argument.  So 'nothing' 'satisfies its requirment.

Comment: But that does not explain why '?' is permitted. Either way, I have just run my tests on my new code and the tests for the list without a query now fail (they were fine before I added query argument). Perhaps my entire approach is wrong. Is there anyway to make an optional but not require user to do a thing like -b before they provide the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get too focused on the "required".  The fundamental distinction in `argparse` (other POSIX style parsers) is between "flagged" arguments, and "positionals".  "flagged", also commonly called "optionals", take some sort of flag string, commonly  prefixed with a dash or two (though this can be changed).  A "positional" is "identified" by position, that is word order.  Some parsers require a specific order, either all options first, or all after, the positionals.  `argparse` shows positionals after optionals in the usage, but tries, where possible, to handle any order.

`argparse` also provides a `required` parameter for flagged arguments, and allows `nargs` like '?', '+', '*', '...', that handle a variable number of arguments.  And some flagged ones don't take any argument (True/False).

Help group names like "required", "optional", "positional"  don't reflect all possibilites, so don't take them too literally.

A simple script that takes two file names, and one or more control values might look something like this:

```
In [1]: import argparse    
In [2]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   ...: parser.add_argument('-f','--foo')
   ...: parser.add_argument('input')
   ...: parser.add_argument('output', nargs='?', default='outfile')
```

'[]' are used in usage to give a hit as to which strings are required, and which may be omitted.  If I defined a '-g' with `required=True`, it would still be grouped with `optional`, since it is not a `positional`.

```
In [3]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-f FOO] input [output]

positional arguments:
  input
  output

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -f FOO, --foo FOO
```

Sample runs:

```
In [4]: parser.parse_args([])
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-f FOO] input [output]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: input
...
  
In [5]: parser.parse_args('in'.split())
Out[5]: Namespace(foo=None, input='in', output='outfile')

In [6]: parser.parse_args('in out -f foobar'.split())
Out[6]: Namespace(foo='foobar', input='in', output='out')
```

All defined arguments can be seen in the `_actions` list, and each has a 'required' attribute:

```
In [8]: parser._actions
Out[8]: 
[_HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=['-f', '--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='input', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='output', nargs='?', const=None, default='outfile', type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)]

In [9]: [a.required for a in parser._actions]
Out[9]: [False, False, True, False]
```

The `output` positional is not `required`, because of its `nargs` value.